# Response times long for multiple users in Cloud Run for a Django application

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I have a Django Rest Framework application which is hosted in Cloud Run. The normal response times for requests are around 100-200ms but no matter what I try I cannot get the same response times for multiple users.

I have conducted load testing with Jmeter: for 200 users the best I can get is 1500ms average response time and for 500 around 4000ms (these are for "hot" instances). I have tried setting different values for gunicorn workers and thread (such as setting the max concurrency the same as # of cores * # of threads and setting the workers count the same as the number of CPUs and 2 * # of CPUs + 1) as well as trying with different CPU, memory and max instances and concurrent requests settings. I also checked that the Cloud SQL has sufficient CPU. What could be the bottleneck here?